# R code: Saving elapsed time as a single number with a consistent scale

Tags: r, time

In R, I'm try to save the elapsed time of some lines of code (not a function execution).  However, I'm having trouble getting it boiled down to a single number with a consistent scale (for example, all in total seconds).  For example, I have tried:

```
starttime <- Sys.time() 
... 
timeelapsed <- as.Double(Sys.time()-starttime)
```

The problem is that timeelapsed can represent seconds, minutes, or some other unit of time passing, depending on how much actual time has elapsed.

Comment: Use `microbenchmark` from `microbenchmark` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
as.numeric(Sys.time() - starttime, units = "secs")
```

You can specify units as `"mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"` as outlined by `?difftime` documentation.

`Sys.time() - starttime` is inherently `difftime` class, since it's the subtraction of two `POSIXct` objects

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
starttime=Sys.time()
..
..
..
endtime=Sys.time()
timeelapsed=difftime(as.POSIXct(endtime),as.POSIXct(starttime),units="secs")
```

•units can take : “auto”, “secs”, “mins”, “hours”, “days”, “weeks”

•value of timeelapsed can be accessed using as.numeric(timeelapsed)